# How to count occurrences of attributes using XQuery

Tags: xml, xquery

I am using XQuery to count occurrences of related comments, on a thread on Social Media. However, I only want to count these occurrences, if the comments are made by females. (This is for a gender related research project at Uni.

So far I have got XQuery to count all the occurrences of the comments made by females by using this:

```
for $t in doc ("women.xml")
let $a:=$t//comment/@gender="female"
return count ($a)
```

However I need some help working out how I would adapt this to account the occurrences of appearance specific comments said by females.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Post sample XML containing comments you do and do not want selected, and specify clearly a criteria that distinguishes ones you want from ones you do not want.  Without such details, your question is unanswerable beyond saying that `count(//comment[@gender="female"])` will return the number of `comment` elements with `@gender` attribute values equal to `"female"`.

Answer (score 2):

First, note that

```
let $a:=$t//comment/@gender="female" return count ($a)
```

always returns 1. That's because the result of "=" is a boolean, and a boolean value is a sequence of length 1. What you intended is

```
let $a:=$t//comment[@gender="female"] return count ($a)
```

or more simply

```
count($t//comment[@gender="female"])
```

Now, if you only want to define "appearance-specific" comments, you can do

```
count($t//comment[@gender="female"][local:is-appearance-specific(.)])
```

and then you need to define a function

```
declare function local:is-appearance-specific(
        $c as element(comment)) as xs:boolean {
   ....
};
```

which returns true if the comment is considered "appearance-specific".